# Do standard NiMh AA or AAA battery's have any kind of BMS or protection circuit built-in?

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, circuit-protection, batteries

Do standard rechargeable NiMh AA or AAA battery's have any kind of protection circuit like over discharge? Or are there any circuits out there that do that kind of stuff? I want to power my Arduino Nano with two AA battery's. Any suggestions? Do I need extra protection circuits to prevent any damage to the battery or do they shut of themself when they reach the 1v mark?

Comment: Monitor the voltage with the Arduino and put it to sleep when the voltage drops?

Comment: Do you mean LiMh? They don't exist. I suspect you mean Li-ion.

Comment: You can power an Arduino with the 3 V from two regular Alkaline AA cells. You might have to: 1) remove or short a voltage regulator 2) lower the "brownout" detection voltage of the ATMega chip. The ATMega chip on an Arduino nano can work from 2.7 V and higher so 2x 1.5 V Alkaline cells provide enough voltage. I've done this myself before and it works fine.

Comment: Did you mean NiMH?

Comment: alkaline drop 33% for full capacity to 1V but there are plenty of LDO’s with threshold for UVLO or DC OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, standard, "off the shelf" NiMH batteries have no electronics or monitoring system.

If you want a circuit to prevent draining low batteries, look for UVLO or Under Voltage circuits or ICs.

https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/50002561A-1102171.pdf is an application sheet for a MCP16251 One-Cell Boost Converter with an External UVLO Circuit, compromised of basic transistors and resistors. The MCP16251 can also boost 2 NiMH cells up to 5V if needed. But there are other dedicated UVLO ICs or NiMH.

Then again, NiMH doesn't suffer catastrophic damage if you try to drain them too much, unlike Lithium cells, so you could skip this if you want.

Comment: Not catastrophic but some chargers will refuse to charge them when the voltage falls to 0.